# Add Digital signature to PDF using openPDF

Tags: java, pdf, digital-signature, openpdf

Could anyone provide a example of how to add digital signature to PDF using openPDF.
I have looked at the openPDF gitHUb link https://github.com/LibrePDF/OpenPDF/wiki/Signing
and tried to use what is avilable in PdfSignatureAppreanceTest, but i dont see the PDF modified with the signature.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: My guess is that the pdf does get signed, its just not visible. Have you tried opening it with Acrobat reader and checking if the sign is added.